# Mysql syntax Error when creating a table #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

When I create a table in my localhost and it says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
>     `register_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
>     `last_login` DATETIME NOT NUL' at line 6"

(WampServer v 3.0.6 64bit, Apache 2.4.23 - MySql 5.7.14)

I've already try to change DB engine into InnoDB but the error was still appear.

Here is my Query

```
CREATE TABLE `inventry`.`users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    `usertype` ENUM(0) NOT NULL,
    `register_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `last_login` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `notes` VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

U P D A T E D******

I want store data in this field. but when i save this it getting error. How can i fix this.?

[image: ENUM]

Comment: "An enumeration value **must be a quoted string literal**," ([ENUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)). Furthermore: "We strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as enumeration values, because it does not save on storage over the appropriate TINYINT or SMALLINT type, and it is easy to mix up the strings and the underlying number values (which might not be the same) if you quote the ENUM values incorrectly. If you do use a number as an enumeration value, always enclose it in quotation marks. If the quotation marks are omitted, the number is regarded as an index."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below -

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
usertype ENUM('0') NOT NULL,
register_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
last_login DATETIME NOT NULL,
notes VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
primary key (id)
)
```

Comment: If `ENUM(0)` is really the only error, then you should be voting to close as a typo, and not answering.

Comment: execute his statement, you can see what other errors are!!

Comment: [There are no other errors besides the ENUM problem](https://rextester.com/MQP34160).

Answer (score 1):

just put, ENUM values, in quotes

```
CREATE TABLEinventry.users(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    usertype ENUM(**'0'**) NOT NULL,
    register_dateDATETIME NOT NULL,
    last_loginDATETIME NOT NULL,
    notesVARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```